# How do I prove that this series converges.

Tags: calculus

$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$ 
I know I probably have to use the test for divergence to prove the sum converges. When I took the limit I got: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$
I will have to use L'Hospital's rule, but how do I take the derivative of the denominator? Or would I have to use the comparison theorem?

Comment: Depends what you know. One can find an explicit sum. Or use Ratio Test. Or show that soon the $n$-th term is $\lt \frac{1}{n^2}$ and use comparison. Or note that the $n$-th term is less than $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ratio test: Let $a_n = \frac{n}{(n+1)!} $

$$ \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!} \frac{ (n+1)!}{n} = \frac{n+1}{n(n+2)} \to 0 < 1$$

Hence, $\sum a_n $ converges

Comment: I don't believe I can use the ratio test.

Comment: @user111392 Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compare this series to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$